# Update paddings of items in RecyclerView after notifyItemRemoved()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, padding

I have set different paddings for items on a RecyclerView depending on its position on the RecyclerView,these values are set in the `onBindView()`.Now whenever I remove an item and call `notifyItemRemoved()`,the paddings of the items are not updated instead they still hold their previous paddings.How can I update the item paddings when the RecyclerView item positions are changed.

Comment: If padding of items depends on item position then you have to call `notifyDataSetChanged` to notify all Items. `notifyItemRemoved` will only update only one row . So its all depends upon how are u calculating padding for each item.

Comment: Calling notifyDataSetChanged will make the recycleview blink.

Comment: It will not if it is then you can turn off the change animations . Since I do not know the how are u calculating padding I can not provide a proper solution. So u might wanna edit your question with adapter code